# save state when phone turned off

Tags: ios, appdelegate, savestate

I created a saveState() method that uses UserDefaults to save certain settings at certain parts of my App. It works fine when I exit the App and return, but if I actually turn my (iOS) phone off, when I start the App again, the settings are not saved.  In addition to those places where I call the saveState() method in the code, I also call saveState() in three AppDelegate functions:  applicationWillResignActive, applicationDidEnterBackground and applicationWillTerminate.  I have a loadState() function in viewDidLoad so any saved information will load at that time.  Does anyone know what I am not doing re: saving/restoring settings when phone powered off?

Comment: Rather than relying on specifc events to trigger a save (and there is no event that lets your app know the phone is being turned off), you should save your data any time it changes, then it doesn't matter what happens

Comment: Thanks Paulw11!  So, I think you are saying that if I use the Userdefaults at specific (change) points in my Application, then I don't need to do an additional saving of the State in AppDelegate --- it's already done.  Is that right?

Comment: That's right. There is no real cost to saving so you might as well do it any time you change the data

Answer (score 0):

When iphone off, AppDelegate's `applicationWillTerminate`

function Called when the application is about to terminate

how about use `synchronize()` after your saveState() called

In apple API https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/userdefaults/1414005-synchronize

> Writes any modifications to the persistent domains to disk and updates all unmodified persistent domains to what is on disk.

Comment: `applicationWillTerminate` may not be called.  The OP states that they have already implemented this function.